# Arduino timer within a timer

Tags: timer, arduino

Arduino Nano and I need a timer within a timer and having some problems getting my head around the logic. I have played with some Libraries on GitHub, Timer, SimpleTimer and Metro but none seem to do what I need. Or, if they can I can't seem to get them to do it.

I need to switch a relay on for about 2-minutes and then off, every hour. I am trying

```
loop
{ if (millis() - 3600000 > TimeMax)
  { relay(on);
    if (millis() - 12000 > relayMax)
    TimeMax = millis();
  }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work and I need this to all stay working within the "loop" as I have an nRF24L radio listening.

Could someone please help me with code snippets or at least an outline how to go about this.

Thanks

Comment: why nest timers? can't you have the outer time trigger in the inner one? have one timer turn the relay on and also activates another timer which kicks in 2 minutes later to shut off the relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all *timers* in embedded dev speak means interrupts that gets fired after a delay. Generally speaking you want interrupts to handle very atomic actions, because you don't want to have an interrupt triggered while another one is triggered, because that could be the scenario of a horror movie.

But why would you want to make something hard, complex and overengineered, when it can be simple?

All you need to do is handle it through a simple dual state machine:

```
#define OPEN_DELAY 120*1000
#define CLOSE_DELAY 3600*1000 
// N.B.: to be precise here, to make 2 minutes every hour, 
// CLOSE_DELAY should be 3600*1000-OPEN_DELAY so it
// does not shift by 2 minutes every hour. 

void loop() {
    static bool open=false;
    static long timestamp = millis();

    if (!open && millis()-timestamp > CLOSE_DELAY) {
        open=true;            // change state
        timestamp = millis(); // rearm timestamp
        set_relay_on();
    } else if (open && millis()-timestamp > OPEN_DELAY) {
        open=false;
        timestamp = millis();
        set_relay_off();
    }
}
```

The only reason you might want to use timer would be to save battery by keeping the AVR in sleep mode as much as possible. Then you'd set the timer to the biggest possible value before putting it to sleep, making it wake up the AVR with an interrupt every few seconds or so, so then you run the `loop()` once in `CLOSE` state going back to sleep — there you don't need to write an ISR, the main loop() is enough, or keeping it up for the full two minutes in `OPEN` state.

There's good documentation on timers you might want to read (beware the headaches, though):

- http://maxembedded.com/2011/06/introduction-to-avr-timers/

Here's how to put the arduino to sleep for long delays:

- http://www.bot-thoughts.com/2013/11/avr-watchdog-as-sleep-delay.html

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I appreciate the detail you went into.